# Unable to send data from my server to client

Tags: java

I made a simple chat program where sending data from MyClient to MyServer is working, but when sending data from MyServer to MyClient is not working.
 So where I'm making mistake?

This is MyServer program:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;

public class MyServer{

    ServerSocket ss;
       Socket s;
        DataInputStream din;
        DataOutputStream dout;


public MyServer(){

    try{

        System.out.println("Server START......");

            ss=new ServerSocket(9000);
            s=ss.accept();

            System.out.println("Client Connected.....");

            din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                chat();
        }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);}
}

public void chat()throws IOException{

    String str=" ";

        do{
            str=din.readUTF();

            System.out.println("Client Message: "+str);

            dout.writeUTF("I have recieved ur message:"+str);
            dout.flush();

            }while(!str.equals("stop"));
}

public static void main(String arg[]){

    new MyServer();}
}
```

This is MyClient program:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;

public class MyClient{

    Socket s;
        DataInputStream din;
        DataOutputStream dout;

public MyClient(){

    try{
        s=new Socket("localhost",9000);

        System.out.println(s);

            din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                chat();

        }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);}
}

public void chat()throws IOException{

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String s1;

    do{
        s1=br.readLine();

        dout.writeUTF(s1);
        dout.flush();

        System.out.println("Server Message: "+din.readUTF());

        }while(!s1.equals("stop"));
}

public static void main(String arg[]){

    new MyClient();}
}
```

Comment: You have a BufferedReader scanning for console input in your client, which is then sent to the Server. You have nothing scanning for console input in your Server, so if you're trying to send a message from the Server's console to the Client's, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you already do send an information from the server to the client with "I have received your message..."...

Anyway. If you want to send messages from the server to the client like a chat program your code should looks like this:

The Server part:

```
public class Server {

ServerSocket ss;
Socket s;
DataInputStream din;
DataOutputStream dout;

public Server() {

    try {

        System.out.println("Server START......");

        ss = new ServerSocket(9000);
        s = ss.accept();

        System.out.println("Client Connected.....");

        din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        chat();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void chat() throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String s1;

    do {

        System.out.println("Client Message: " + din.readUTF());

        s1=br.readLine();
        dout.writeUTF(s1);
        dout.flush();

    } while (!s1.equals("stop"));
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {

    new Server();
}
```

}

And for the client:

```
public class Client {

Socket s;
DataInputStream din;
DataOutputStream dout;

public Client() {

    try {
        s = new Socket("localhost", 9000);

        System.out.println(s);

        din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        chat();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public void chat() throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String s1;

    do {

        s1 = br.readLine();

        dout.writeUTF(s1);
        dout.flush();   

        System.out.println("Server Message: " + din.readUTF());

    } while (!s1.equals("stop"));
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {

    new Client();
}
```

}